# Can I use a .NET 4.8 assembly that has COM support from a .NET 8.0 assembly

Tags: c#, .net, com, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

I have a .NET framework 4.8 assembly that supports COM, it has a typelib.

I tried to add it as a COM reference to my .NET 8.0 assembly, but got this error:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3010,5): warning MSB3290:
> Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{ce9f57a9-86a1-49a2-8aa9-63ec6d8a7afb}". Type library 'LMF_Tracker_Connection' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.

I was hoping that I could use COM to use the .NET assembly's classes in my .NET 8.0 assembly.

Has anyone done anything like this before?

I registered my assembly using a bat file like this

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm /u /tlb LMF.Tracker.Connection.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase LMF.Tracker.Connection.dll /tlb
```

I right clicked on my project dependencies and picked Add COM Reference then picked my typelib.

The reference had an exclamation mark against it and I saw the error message that I quoted above.

I haven't tried this before but I expected to see some classes added to my project that I could use to drive the other assembly via COM.

PS: I am going to ask the manufacturer for an updated assembly, my attempt to use COM is just a holding action until they get round to making a new assembly.

Comment: Check this sample: https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/NetComSxS

Comment: Perhaps you mean ".NET Framework 4.8" (which is not part of the same numeric sequence as ".NET 8.0")

Comment: @ben Thanks, I thought framework but didn't type it.

Comment: @serg I'm really hoping that there is something that could take the typelib and generate the "glue code" that is in the Contracts/IServer.cs file.

Comment: @johnsphere, you can use `tlbimp` to generate an interop assembly with all the declarations you need and then reference that assembly (as a `dll`) instead of `ComReference`. Or just grab the code of generated assembly and paste it into the project.

Comment: Calling a .NET Framework COM object from .NET 8 works fine, but no .NET version can import a TLB created by .NET Framework. What you can do is rewrite manually (in a .cs) the interfaces that were defined in the COM object (or decompile it with a tool like ILSpy), ie: you cannot "reference" the .NET Framework project. Once you've done that you can instantiate it like this `var obj = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(yourClsid));`

Comment: @SimonMourier, I may be wrong , but if all the required "magic" attributes like `[ComImport]/[CoClass]/[Guid]` are set correctly for the COM interface declaration, then you can just write `new IMyInterface()` instead of the `Activator` stuff.

Comment: @serg - In pure COM yes, but .NET doesn't like .NET tlb...

Comment: @johnsphere Hi, Simon Mourier's comment was helpful. I posted his comment as an answer. You can mark it (click the check mark to the left of the answer) so that it can help more people.

Comment: @WenbinGeng I will have a look at this after sprint planning and see how I get on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Simon Mourier said:

Calling a .NET Framework COM object from .NET 8 works fine, but no .NET version can import a TLB created by .NET Framework. What you can do is rewrite manually (in a .cs) the interfaces that were defined in the COM object (or decompile it with a tool like ILSpy), ie: you cannot "reference" the .NET Framework project. Once you've done that you can instantiate it like this `var obj = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID (yourClsid));`

Comment: Nobody on my team wants me spending any more time on this. My hardware adaptor is its own app and communicates with the rest of our software via gRPC, so it can be a framework 4.8 app and use the manufacturer's assembly directly. I had planned to use Kestrel to provide a web api and some pages for my UI, but I can just use WPF. Maybe, in time, tlibimp can import framework assemblies into .Net assemblies. I will mark the answer as an answer but I haven't tested it. :-)